# How to get individual process data from list of process data in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am getting the process name ,user name, process time using the below script in PowerShell

```
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
$data = @{}
get-process | select processname,Id,PrivilegedProcessorTime,UserProcessorTime,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

It is giving the data as

```
ProcessName             : UpdaterUI
  Id                      : 6824
  PrivilegedProcessorTime : 00:00:04.6332297
  UserProcessorTime       : 00:00:04.1964269
  Owner                   : VM82958
```

I would like to get data of individual process I tried the below code

```
foreach($val in $data) { 
    $processname = $val.ProcessName
    $processname = $val.Owner
    $processname = $val.PrivilegedProcessorTime
    $processname = $val.UserProcessorTime

}
```

But I am not getting any information. can any one help me how to get the information of individual process data ,and PrivilegedProcessorTime,UserProcessorTime data in TotalMilliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just *assign*  the result to `$data`:

```
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
$data = get-process | select processname,Id,PrivilegedProcessorTime,UserProcessorTime,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

In the first example you populate the hashtable `$owners` within the `ForEach-Object` pipeline (alias `%`). Whereas you don't populate `$data` anywhere.